# Append to array in Clickhouse

Tags: database, clickhouse

Is it possible to append a certain value to all the records that satisfy certain condition in Clickhouse, if not what are other options to do the same.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried to search for it in the documentation here (https://clickhouse.yandex/reference_en.html) but couldn't find it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updates and deletes aren't supported on clickhouse, so not possible .

Answer (score 1):

You can not modify data in the table, as all data in ClickHouse is immutable.

**But**: you can add that **on the fly** during select, or you can make a VIEW which will do it for you.

If you really need that column stored in changed state - you need to create table copy, or a materialized view.

Those functions can be usefull arrayConcat, arrayPushBack, arrayPushFront (documentation is upcoming).

So

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN condition > 10 THEN arrayPushBack(array_field, 'extra_element')
    ELSE array_field
  END
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        10 AS condition, ['a', 'b'] AS array_field
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        101, ['c', 'd']
);
```

Answer (score 1):

However, Clickhouse currently doesn't support editing rows in a table. 
It is possible to add a column with expression where source array could be modified and then realize swap column logic by combining add/drop a column commands.

Then Clickhouse allows removing column with command ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name. Source column could be removed and created a column with a needed array from the intermediate column with the same name as the source column.

But you can drop/add the column which isn't participating in index keys and I would remind that this solution could be high resource consuming for adding/dropping columns for big tables.